# Can we use the task list from "another" web site of same site collection as task list for Sharepoint Workflow?

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

Can I specify/use an existing task list from "another" website but from same site collection to be used in my Sequential Sharepoint Workflow? I am using Visual Studio to code the workflow, and it will be deployed in /subsite, the root site already has a task list to which everyone has connected to Outlook etc...Instead of creating a new task list in /subsite and asking concerned to subscribe to this new task list...I want to use the existing one..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be mistaking, but, as looking up for this information with reflector, i find there is a method [SPWorkflowAssociation.SetTaskList(SPList)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflow.spworkflowassociation.settasklist.aspx).

Looks hopefull. But, within this this method, such thing happens:

```
this.EnsureListInThisWeb(list);
```

method definition:

```
private void EnsureListInThisWeb(SPList list)
{
    if ((this.m_templates != null) && (list.ParentWeb.ID != this.m_templates.ParentWeb.ID))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(SPResource.GetString("WorkflowAssociationListNotInWeb", new object[0]));
    }
}
```

So it checks if list's parentweb is equal to web where workflow associations are. If not, you get the exception.

So my answer would be **no, you can't have task list in another web**.